# C# Graph API creating draft with MIME content, unable to retrieve draft id

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, message

I'm attempting to create a draft email in Office 365 using MIME content via the Graph API, and retrieve the draft id. The approach I've taken is to modify the HTTP Request Message with the MIME content StringContent, and then to send the http request "manually". The problem is that I can't find the draft id of the newly created draft in the response from this call. Is this the correct approach to be taking here? How do I get the draft id?

```
var draftMessagesRequest = graphClient
  .Users[sendFrom]
  .Messages
  .Request()
  .GetHttpRequestMessage();

  draftMessagesRequest.Content = content;
  draftMessagesRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

var draftMessageResponse = await graphClient
  .HttpProvider
  .SendAsync(draftMessagesRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the Location header! (need to parse it out of the string value which includes url etc)